# Traffic Splitting By IP Address on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to direct traffic to different versions of Google App Engine code based on a set list of known IP Addresses.

For example, if an incoming request is from an IP Address on a given list, then traffic is directed to version 1. If not, then version 2.

Is there a way to do this from the admin console or deployment configuration?

The end goal is to grant access to extra features when the site is accessed from an approved IP Address. If I can't do this from the admin console, then I plan to get the IP Address during the user's login process, and set their security role based on IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way within the admin console or deployment process. However, if you do cookie-based traffic splitting, you can set the cookie yourself (based on the incoming IP address, or another value you desire). The value is stored in `GOOGAPPUID` and the value you'd want to use is described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting#Routing), and varies depending on the number of versions you're splitting between and the respective levels of traffic you'd like to send to each version.

If you don't want to do traffic splitting for users *not* on a given list of IPs, you should make sure to explicitly set the cookie for all users. Otherwise, App Engine will provide the value (and send some users to both versions) by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope there is a white-list feature built into the admin console someday, but for now your suggestions help.