# Setting GOOGAPPUID to the correct version when traffic splitting on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cookies

I have setup traffic splitting between two versions of my application on Google App Engine and would like to control which version a user sees.

According to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/trafficsplitting#The_Types_of_Splitting) and this question on stackoverflow: [Traffic Splitting By IP Address on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032531/traffic-splitting-by-ip-address-on-google-app-engine) this can be done by setting a value in a cookie.

According to the documentation: `Set-Cookie: GOOGAPPUID=... header. This allows your app to control which version a user gets.` where GOOGAPPUID is a number between 0-999 representing the version I would like to show.

I have tried to figure out which value to use for each version by splitting my traffic between two version where each should receive 50%. I then cleared my cache, loaded the site and looked at the cookie-information. I did this several times and got the following values:

- 215
- 362
- 671

I have named my versions 3.0 and 4.0 but where do I see which values each version is mapped to so I can control which value the users see ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to print some version value on both of your code. Like in version 3.0, print "version:3.0" in your index page and on version 4.0, print "version:4.0". And check which one gets loaded every time you refresh if you are not able to find version in cookies list.

Though this is not a right solution, just a way out.